# SSJS Rows.Update not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I'm facing a problem that I don't know how to fix. 
Basically I'm trying to get all the contacts inside a custom DE and change their status to "Unsubscribe" in the AllSubscribers. 
This will be used inside a Script Activity, but I'm running it inside a CloudPage for debbuging with Try&Catch in some way..
My code:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

try{

    var subKey = [];
    var allSubs = DataExtension.Init("AllSubs_ExternalKey"); // AllSubscribers
    var myDE = DataExtension.Init("Custom_ExternalKey"); //my custom DE
    var rows = myDE.Rows.Retrieve();
    
    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){

        subKey.push(rows[i].ContactId_);

    }
    
    allSubs.Rows.Update({Status: "Unsubscribed"}, ["SubscriberKey"], subKey);

}catch(error){

    Write("Error: " + Stringify(error));
    
}
```

The first time everything worked pretty well(Status changed to "Unsubscribed" correctly).. but after 3 hours I've tried again and got this:
**Error: "There was an error Updating the row(s)."**

I thought it was caused by the method Rows.Update that maybe can't unsubscribe a contact already unsubscribed, so I made a script that took and remove these contacts, but it didn't work.
Am I doing anything wrong in the code?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Do you actually have a data extension called All Subscribers? Or are you trying to update your All Subscribers list?

Comment: I'm trying to update the main list that contains all the subscribers/contacts in Marketing Cloud with their information like: SubscriberKey, EmailAddress, Status, CreatedDate, etc..

Comment: You can't do it like this. All Subscribers is not a data extension, so you will need to treat it as a list, using this SSJS: https://www.salesforcefan.com/post/add-update-all-subscribers-from-data-extension-via-ssjs